# How to compile imageclipper in 12.04

Tags: compiling, boost

I've been trying to compile [imageclipper](https://code.google.com/p/imageclipper/) unsuccessfully, I've already installed opencv and boost and build-essential (gcc version is 4.6.3).

The problem comes when modifying the Makefile, I need to replace two variables according to my system.

Originally these variables are like this:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -I ~/usr/include/boost-1_36 -I.
LFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs opencv` -L ~/usr/lib -lboost_system-gcc41-mt -lboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt
```

I installed boost through synaptic (installed `libboost-all-dev`), how can I find the installation paths to `boost` and `lboost_system-gcc41-mt`?

edit: After making a little more of research, my Makefile is:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -I /usr/include/boost -I.
LFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs opencv` -L /usr/lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt
```

Now I got this error:

```
In file included from imageclipper.cpp:43:0:
filesystem.h: In function ‘std::string fs::realpath(const string&)’:
filesystem.h:60:23: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h: In function ‘std::string fs::dirname(const string&)’:
filesystem.h:66:37: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h: In function ‘std::string fs::basename(const string&)’:
filesystem.h:72:28: error: could not convert ‘boost::filesystem3::path::leaf() const()’ from ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
filesystem.h: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > fs::filelist(const string&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, std::string)’:
filesystem.h:129:44: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h:131:50: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h:133:50: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h:135:50: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h:137:50: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
filesystem.h:139:50: error: ‘class boost::filesystem3::path’ has no member named ‘native_file_string’
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally could make it work, just needed to replace `native_file_string()` with `string()`.
And inside `basename` function replaced `return fspath.leaf()` with `return boost::filesystem::basename(path)`